# What is the German translation of the 'On' preposition in scientific paper titles?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, scientific-language

For example, a scientific paper which is called 'On the Treatment of Concordant Uranium-Lead Ages', how would the German scientific community translate the title and specifically the 'on' preposition?

Would it be "Zur Behandlung konkordanter Uran-Blei-Alter" or "Auf die Behandlung von Concordant Uran-Blei Alter"? So basically is the common widely accepted translation for "on" in this context be "zu" or "auf"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*"Auf"* does not fit. Traditionally, it's either *"über" (+ Akk.)* or *"zu" (+ Dat.)*, e.g.,

- *Zur Theorie des Gesetzes der Energieverteilung im Normalspektrum.*
- *Über das Gesetz der Energieverteilung im Normalspektrum.*

There is also the longer phrase *"Ein Beitrag zum/zur ..."*, corresponding to the English *"A contribution on the ...".*

On the other hand, in STEM fields, scientific articles are typically
not published in German nowadays, and in those academic disciplines where
articles are still published in German on a regular basis (e.g., law),
this naming style seems to (have) become unpopular: Authors are more likely to write *"Die Strafbarkeit von Cum/Ex-Geschäften"* than *"Zur Strafbarkeit von Cum/Ex-Geschäften"*.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This short hand taken from booktitles, the conjunction what should be a preposition is kept in the title, while a verb that belonged with the preposition is omitted

> ## Die Ludolfs
>
> ### [schwadronieren] über die Gesetze des Nudelkochens

the öreposition in spe commanding the appropriate verb--I mean it uses *über* or *zu* pretty much invariably--implies it was always a preverb. Compare "Hermann, zu mir!"